# Regex : Find a number between parentheses and a specific string

Tags: regex

I would like to find lines where there is a number between a parentheses and string `BAC` after it

For exemple

```
ABABBAB (87490), BAC  ===> OK
BLABLABLA (65688), BIC  ===> Not OK
ABABBAB (75664), EEE  ===> Not OK
```

I Have found an answer to get numbers between parentheses

`^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\).*$` here an [example](https://rubular.com/r/ImZaRigMv5)

Now I would like to add the condition to match also the `BAC` string

Comment: Which tool or regex library are you using?

Comment: this website https://rubular.com/r/ImZaRigMv5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\),\s+BAC\s*$
```

`,` — direct match

`\s+` — one or more spaces

`BAC` — direct match

`\s*` — zero or more spaces

---

If you'd like to match *and report* an arbitrary word, this should work:

```
^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\)\s+(\S+).*$
```

`\S+` — one or more non-space characters

---

To match `BAC,` followed by anything:

```
^.*?\([^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*\),\s+BAC,.*$
```

Comment: I'm trying it on this example , it does not work `AFRAM (19898), BAC, 2019X 98989, dép,`

Comment: Actually I would the specific `BAC` word, I updated my question to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using a capture group with the following regex:

```
(?<=\()\d+(?=\))(?=.*\bBAC\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0d4wIH/1/)

Each string of one or more digits surrounded by parentheses and followed by the word `BAC` (but not `BACK` or `ABAC`, for example) is matched.

This regex works with PCRE (PHP), Python, Javascript, Onigmo regex engines, and others that support fixed-length positive look-behinds and positive look-aheads. See the comparison chart [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines#See_also).

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=\()        # match '(' in a positive lookbehind
\d+            # match 1+ digits
(?=\))         # match ')' in a positive lookahead
(?=.*\bBAC\b)  # match 0+ chars followed by `BAC` with word breaks fore and aft
```